# OnFocusChangeListener doesn't work on Textview in android

Tags: android, focus, listener

There are two textview: textview1 and textview2, and their background color are white initially.I want to implement such an effect:

Click textview1—— textview1 turns black and textview2 turns white;

Click textview2—— textview1 turns white and textview1 turns black;

**Obviously, I need to set OnFocusChangeListener on them, and set their XML attribute "focusable=true", as answered by many people in stackoverflow.**

```
  <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:id="@+id/text1"
       android:textSize="50dp"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:text="xxxxxxxxxxx"

       />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="50dp"
       android:text="yyyyyyyyyyyy"
       android:id="@+id/text2"
       android:focusable="true"

       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text1"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView1=findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                }else{
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
                }
            }
        });
        TextView textView2=findViewById(R.id.text2);
        textView2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                }else{
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
                }
            }
        });

//        textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                v.requestFocus();
//            }
//        });
//        textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                v.requestFocus();
//            }
//        });
    }
}
```

But they don't work.I enter the debug mode, and find the truth that the "onFocusChange" never be triggered.

**The only way they work, is to set their XML attributes android:focusableInTouchMode="true",but that's not I want, because I have to click a textview twice to trigger an OnClick event after setting this attribute. Besides,I believe it's not an elegant way to do this——I need to know the reason why setOnFocusChangeListener doesn't work.**

Comment: Try onTouchListener, it should work. Or I don't get ur idea properly

Comment: It seems that onTouchListener doesn's has a field or method to tell whether the textview is unselected? And I am more intersted to know why setOnClickListener can't be triggered.